# Ignore finger resting at the bottom of trackpad [unibody macbook pro]

Tags: touchpad, mac, multi-touch, trackpad, macosx

I have 2 finger scrolling working, and the three finger window movement works great, but something thats really bothering me is that I can't rest my thumb on the bottom of the trackpad like I can in osx. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't support proper detection of trackpads for macbook pros (I'm assuming it's an integrated button trackpad). This is changing in 12.04. However, for the time being I would recommend using this driver:

https://github.com/BlueDragonX/xf86-input-mtrack

(Thanks to C S for pointing out it's in the repos) Install the driver: [xserver-xorg-input-mtrack](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xserver-xorg-input-mtrack) [image: Install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack]

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
```

Add this to your xorg.conf file after installing the driver:

```
Section "InputClass"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Identifier      "Touchpads"
    Driver          "mtrack"
    Option         "IgnorePalm" "true" EndSection
```

Restart your xserver (or computer) when finished. There are other fun options, take a look at the github page for more.

Comment: Alternatively, type at the terminal `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack`

Comment: ohh cool did this finally make it into the archives? :-) I'm guessing so.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I'm very excited for 12.04 in this case!

Comment: How do I add that to my repos? Ben

Comment: Oh man, I want to use this driver so badly, but the speed is just so off. If it becomes official in 12.04, I really hope that it gets tweaked to be as nice as the default one in 11.10, just with the added bonus of being able to use my thumb.

Comment: @zookalicious you can adjust the speed.

Comment: Yeah but even then the acceleration is wonky. It's hard to describe, but I spent hours and hours tweaking it and it still felt off. As in it would move slowly, and then suddenly fly across the screen, or vice versa. I just never had any luck tweaking it, so I'm hoping that if it gets default inclusion that somebody tweaks it for me ^^;

Comment: This driver is not going to be included by default -- I was recommending it as a stop-gap solution until precise.