# Ignore finger resting on trackpad button (Asus s200e)

Tags: touchpad, asus, trackpad

I recently picked up an Asus s200E and installed Ubuntu 13.04; the issue im having is i cannot rest my finger on the buttons while using my other finger to move the cursor without it locking up in place. The touchpad is integrated with the buttons. ive disabled and enabled two finger scrolling without any luck in fixing the problem.

I've tried changing the AreaBottomEdge value so that the buttons become separate from the pad, which works but the same issue still remains with resting my finger on the button.

I've tried older release's with no luck; i've only been able to find this thread on this specific issue:

Thread: [Ignore finger resting at the bottom of trackpad [unibody macbook pro]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105097/ignore-finger-resting-at-the-bottom-of-trackpad-unibody-macbook-pro)

Im relatively new to ubuntu so im here asking for any help, thankyou!

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1026046. Mark as "Affects me to get it fixed faster".

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

create a file /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf with the following line:

```
options psmouse proto=exps
```

and reboot.
This will permit to rest the finger on the "left button" whithout freezing the pointer but you'll lose two finger scrolling and other nice things (may be acceptable until a better fix will be available for the synaptics/multitouch/mtrack xorg input drivers).